# Proportional height value is taken from the xib file not from the device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

It's the first time that I face this stranger problem. I have an `UIViewController` that I create with it's `XIB` file. The screen has two views viewA and viewB. The viewA has those values `top = 0`, `leading = 0`, `trailing = 0`. The `viewA.height = safeArea.height/2`. The viewB constraints are `top = 0`, `leading = 0`, `trailing = 0`, `bottom = 0`. Inside the `viewA` I have a `view` named `viewAbackground` having `top = 0`, `leading = 0`, `trailing = 0`, `bottom = 0` constraints to its container (`viewA`) and I have also some `labels` in the `viewA`. I use this `viewAbackground` to add a `gradient` because If I add it directly to `viewA` it comes in front of the labels. This is how I add the gradient:

```
func createGradientLayer(theView: UIView) {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = theView.frame
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(hexString: Colors.startColor)?.cgColor, UIColor(hexString: Colors.endColor)?.cgColor]
    //add the gradient to the view
    theView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
```

Then in the viewDidLoad I call `createGradientLayer(theView: viewA)`

The `gradient` is added but the problem is that it hasn't the same `size` than the `viewA`. After many hours trying to understand what is wrong, I found that the applied `size` values are the same as what `device` I'm choosing in the `interface Builder` in the `view as` and not the values of my device screen. For example: if in the `xib` I have in the `view as` `iPhone SE`, when I run in the `iPhone 6` I'm getting the `gradient` with the size of the `viewA` in the `iPhone SE`. 
I have `Xcode` 9.2 and I'm using `Swift 4`

Can anyone explain me why I'm having this size problem?

**Edit for more informations:** This is the hierarchy of for the views. `ScrollView <- MainView <- viewA and viewB`. The `mainView` height is equal to the safeArea height. The utility of the scrollView is for the small devices such as the iPhone 4. In this case, I give to the `mainView` a defined height value in order to get the scroll effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your view loads from a xib or storyboard the layout will match what was loaded. As you've noticed, that isn't necessarily going to be the same as the device that it's running on.

So in `viewDidLoad` you will have the size loaded from the data.

In the first call to `viewWillAppear` you see the same sizes.

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called each time the view's bounds change. And this will be the first opportunity to get the views laid out as you would expect for the device that you are running.

Be careful though because you don't want to add your gradient everytime this method is called. However, you may want to update it if the size may change due to device rotation for example.

**Update**
Because you are using a scroll view, viewDidLayoutSubviews may not report the correct values. Possibly a bug in the SDK. You can try getting the correct values from `viewDidAppear` or if that's too late try the solution below.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.setNeedsLayout()
    scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    createGradientLayer(theView: viewA)
}
```

Comment: I called it in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but the problem is still here

Comment: Could there be some other factor that's changing the size of the view after?

Comment: What if you call from `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: also, you should likely be using `theView.bounds` rather than `theView.frame`

Comment: Thank you for your help but I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: Can you provide any more info? What's different about what you are doing? Do you have screenshots of unexpected results?

Comment: yup, it's that scroll view that's causing this. One work around is to call `scrollView.setNeedsLayout(); scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()` before setting the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

This issue connected with misunderstanding of UIViewController lifecycle.

`ViewDidLoad` - Called when you create the class and load from xib. All views will have size you set in xib.

`ViewWillAppear` - Called right before your view appears. At this point all your views will have correct sizes, so you can use their size and position.

Also, `CALayer` doesn't support autoresizing, so, possible you will need to update it's size in `didLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: I have already tried to call it in the `ViewWillAppear` and I get the same problem.

Comment: Can you tell me where and how can I use `didLayoutSubviews` in my case?

Comment: @NeAS overrides it like viewWillAppear method it called viewDidLayoutSubviews and call your createGradientLayer method

Comment: @Hosny I called it in the viewDidLayoutSubviews but I'm getting the same size problem