# Xib dimensions in IB affects final view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I have a problem similar to this one:
[Proportional height value is taken from the xib file not from the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210395/proportional-height-value-is-taken-from-the-xib-file-not-from-the-device)

But mine is a TableView cell, so I don't have access to viewDidLayoutSubviews() which is how that question was solved. I tried overriding the cell's layoutSubviews() but it's still incorrect.

The layout is simply a collection view with leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to the tableview cell. The collection view also has a height constraint, which I use to update the cell size. If I print the collectionView height I can see that it's wrong, but how much it's wrong changes based on the xib.

I've also tried adding a custom slider view to the cell, and the slider also sizes incorrectly until I interact with it, at which point it corrects itself. The initial size of the slider is clearly based on the width of the xib.

I have also set the sizeForRow of the table view to be automaticDimension, and set an estimated row size.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `.collectionViewContentSize` is determined by the collection view's **content** -- how are you setting that?

Comment: In the cellForRow of the tableView. I update an array with the data, then run the code I posted above.

Comment: It's definitely not just the collectionView though, I added another object (a custom slider view) and it also renders based on the xib width.

Comment: Is your collection view using horizontal flow layout? Are you setting the `.itemSize`?

Comment: It's a custom layout as defined here: https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout. Estimated item size is automatic, I'm not setting item size otherwise. I have a view controller elsewhere where I use this method of adjusting the collection view and it works.

Comment: OK - is your collection view sizing itself correctly, but the cell is not?

Comment: Yeah, seems like the cell is laying out its views incorrectly. I'll update the question now that I can see it's not just the collectionView.

Comment: Based on the fact you're having the same issue with *"adding a custom slider view to the cell"*, I think it is a matter of timing more than the "xib width." If you post a [mre] (somewhere like GitHub), I think I can fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. Here's the project whittled down as much as I could. Just run Cameras+Formats in the simulator. You can change the Xib size in GrayHourFrameworks > Classes > FilterTableViewCell and see how it affects the build. https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7j0lfq5ddqwbvj/Minimum%20Repoducible%20TableView.zip?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240967/discussion-between-donmag-and-zakray).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if the XIB is setup, coded and loaded correctly, the size of the XIB in Interface Builder (IB) ***does not*** affect the size of the view at run-time.

Here's a quick, simple example...

For a table view cell XIB with a `UIView` (to which we'll add a shadow and round the corners) with a `UILabel` subview, whether we size the cell in the XIB in IB like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

Using this code:

**DemoTableViewCell**

```
class DemoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        myView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        myView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    }
}
```

**DemoTableViewController**

```
class DemoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let myData: [String] = [
        "Single Line",
        "A longer string which will wrap in Portrait Orientation",
        "This string is long enough that the text will need to word-wrap (on an iPhone 8) whether in Portrait Orientation or Landscape Orientation",
        "Another Single Line",
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Demo Table"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DemoTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! DemoTableViewCell
        cell.label.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

At run-time, we'll get this:

[image]

and note that the layout is automatically handled when the view size changes:

[image]

---

So, a few issues with your designs...

First, trying to use a `UICollectionView` in that way is inherently problematic. Collection views are designed to layout their cells and **scroll** when there are more cells than will fit.

By using the opposite approach - get the size needed to display all the cells and then resize the collection view, all while *embedding it in a table view cell* - is a rather complex task.

In order for the collection view to determine its `contentSize.height`:

- it needs to be given a width
- it needs to get the cell section and items count
- it needs to get the sizes of the cells (particularly if they are not a fixed size)
- it needs to then layout the cells
- **and...** that's an async process
- **and...** in this case, the collection view doesn't get its width until the table view has laid out its cell

Trying to handle the timing on all of that is ***very*** difficult.

Now, since you're throwing away many of the benefits of a collection view (scrolling, cell reuse, etc), and you're likely using a small number of "items" (if you're trying to do this with a couple hundred cells you probably need to re-think your UI design) you're almost certainly better off writing code to layout the views yourself.

---

For a little more detail and code examples, I put up a demo project here: https://github.com/DonMag/TagsTableExample

Comment: Thanks again Don! If anyone wants to see the actual code Don wrote for me to replace this, see our chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240967/discussion-between-donmag-and-zakray